# Loop a command in VxWorks at a certain frequency

Tags: shell, loops, vxworks

I am attempting to loop a command in VxWorks around 6Hz, I cannot compile code for the target in question so I have to use existing VxWorks shell commands

I have tried:

```
repeat(1000,functionX,param1,param2,param3)
```

This works well at repeating the command 1000 times but wont give me the frequency I require

As a comprimise I looked at:

```
period()
```

as this is capable of giving me 1hz calls on the function (which might be acceptable) however I cannot work out how to enter the required parameters into the FunctionX
I have tried both:

```
period(1,functionX,param1,param2,param3)
```

and

```
period(1,functionX(param1,param2,param3))
```

with no luck

Any Ideas on how to acheive the 6Hz rate for FunctionX would be great but if that is not possible without compiling some code then I will settle for a way of getting the period command to work with parameters in the function I am calling

Answer (score 1):

Repeat and period have the same signatures, but the interpretation of the first parameter is different. So if you can call repeat successfully then you can also call period successfully.

```
int period
    (
    int     secs,             /* period in seconds */
    FUNCPTR func,             /* function to call repeatedly */
    int     arg1,             /* first of eight args to pass to func */
    int     arg2,
    int     arg3,
    int     arg4,
    int     arg5,
    int     arg6,
    int     arg7,
    int     arg8
    )



int repeat
    (
    int     n,                /* no. of times to call func (0=forever) */
    FUNCPTR func,             /* function to call repeatedly */
    int     arg1,             /* first of eight args to pass to func */
    int     arg2,
    int     arg3,
    int     arg4,
    int     arg5,
    int     arg6,
    int     arg7,
    int     arg8
    )
```

For `repeat` the first parameter, is the number of times to call the function, and for `period` the first parameter is the period in seconds

So `period` is really too slow for you, and `repeat` is too fast, though you could use `tickGet` to make it work. What you really want is a vxworks  watchdog. Lookup `wdCreate()` and `wdStart()` in your vxworks docs, but be aware that your watchdog handler will be called from an ISR, and so standard ISR precautions should be taken (i.e. you will need a task to do the real work which should pend on a msgQ, or a semaphore that your watchdog handler triggers).

Actually now that I think about it, I believe that `repeat` and `period` also call the handler from an ISR, so technically the same restrictions apply there as well.